# How to call Map.Add from reflection in FSharp?

Tags: dictionary, reflection, f#

Given the following code in the FSI:

```
type Mapping = Map<int,string>

let mm = [ for i in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof<Mapping>).ExportedTypes do yield i]|> List.find(fun m -> m.Name.Contains("MapModule"))
let mt = mm.GetMethod("Empty", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.Public)
let mymap = mt.MakeGenericMethod([|typeof<string>; typeof<string>|]).Invoke(null, [||])

let addmethod = typeof<Mapping>.GetMethod("Add")

addmethod.Invoke(mymap, [|box(1);box("astring")|])
```

The last line produces this error:

> System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>      at .$FSI_0006.main@()
>   Stopped due to error

Even when you switch the `int` and `string` parameters, it gives this error.

Funny thing though, the following code works:

```
type Mapping = Map<string,string>

let mm = [ for i in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof<Mapping>).ExportedTypes do yield i]|> List.find(fun m -> m.Name.Contains("MapModule"))
let mt = mm.GetMethod("Empty", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.Public)
let mymap = mt.MakeGenericMethod([|typeof<string>; typeof<string>|]).Invoke(null, [||])

let addmethod = typeof<Mapping>.GetMethod("Add")
addmethod.Invoke(mymap, [|box("a");box("b")|])
```

So how can I call Map.Add effectively from reflection?

Comment: I'm guessing the `int` in `Map<int, string>` is not being boxed in the F# type, and that's causing your issue, because `1` and `box 1` are not the same type (one is an `int` and the other is an `obj`).

Comment: Any suggestion what to do instead? This also does not work: `addmethod.Invoke(mymap, [|1;"astring"|])`, nor this: `addmethod.Invoke(mymap, [|1 :> obj; "astring" :> obj|])`

Answer (score 2):

Found it.

This line:

```
let mymap = mt.MakeGenericMethod([|typeof<string>; typeof<string>|]).Invoke(null, [||])
```

Should be:

```
let mymap = mt.MakeGenericMethod([|typeof<int>; typeof<string>|]).Invoke(null, [||])
```

The type mismatch was actually a real one, because the "Empty" method was called with the incorrect generic types.

So this is finally the correct code:

```
type Mapping = Map<int,string>

let mm = [ for i in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof<Mapping>).ExportedTypes do yield i]|> List.find(fun m -> m.Name.Contains("MapModule"))
let mt = mm.GetMethod("Empty", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.Public)
let am = mm.GetMethod("Add", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.Public)
let mymap = mt.MakeGenericMethod([|typeof<int>; typeof<string>|]).Invoke(null, [||])
let addmethod = typeof<Mapping>.GetMethod("Add")

addmethod.Invoke(mymap, [|box(1);box("astring")|])
```